# Body Energy Consumption: calculating watts and kwh given calories?

Tags: energy

I want to calculate the energy consumption in watts of the human body from calories consumed.  My number is different than the expected value.  Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

$$E_{\rm day} = \rm 1900\,{cal} = 4.1\,\frac J{cal} \cdot 1900\,{cal} = 7790\,J$$
$$E_{\rm h} = \rm 7790\,J/24\,h = 324\,J/h = 5\,J/s$$
$$E_{\rm s} = \rm 5\,J/s = 5\,watt$$
$$E_{\rm kWh} = \rm 5\,W \cdot 3600\,s = 18,000\,Wh$$

but the expected value is that of an incandescent light bulb at $85\,{\rm W} < E_{\rm s} < \rm 120\,W$. $\ E_{\rm kWh}$ looks wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The value in calories that you've taken is very likely in food calories ($\text{Cal}$), because $1\,900\,\text{cal}$ a day is too little for an average human. The conversion is:

$$1\,\text{food calorie (Cal)} = 1\,000\,\text{ cal}$$

On making this correction, you will get about $92\,\rm W$ of power consumed. Also note that $324\,\rm J/h ≠ 5\,J/s$.

(2) The conversion of J to kWh is missing a factor of $10^3$ (the *kilo* watt-hour)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your intuition was correct, thanks.  I don't think I'm calculating kWh/day correctly as the number seems far too low given the cost of electricity is $\$0.12/kWh$ compared to food.  Do you know the solution?

Comment: @Nick,  I don't see anything else, the power consumption does match the human metabolism rate. Also refrain from editing the post to correct the very mistakes you've asked to find, because it invalidates all of the current answers.

Answer (score 0):

> energy consumption in watts

watt is unit of power, which is joule/second, i.e. energy/time.

1 kcal is 4184 J. 1900 kcal is 7.949.600 J.

1 day has 24 hours or 1440 minutes or 86400 seconds.

7.949.600 J/day equals 92 J/second or 92 W. This number is close to basal human metabolism rate.

If you want to get energy, then 92 W in one hour gives 92 Wh or 0.092 kWh.

Comment: So to get kWh/day is it $92 w * 24 hr = 2.1 kWh$?

Comment: @Nick That is correct

Comment: So if average electric rate is $\$.12/kWh$ USD and the body is supplied by electricity alone as an energy source, it would cost $\$.25/day$ to operate?  On average food is $\$.001/cal$, so $1900 cal$ costs $\$1.90$.  Food is almost 8x more expensive then electricity for the same amount of energy.

Comment: @Nick That is correct. Among other things, that is why we use tractors instead of oxens and horses - the fuel is much cheaper :)